# (Giamarchi) Meaning of slowly varying field in bosonization

Tags: field-theory, bosonization

I am currently reading Giamarchi's Quantum Physics in One Dimension.
Eq. (2.30) of the book says
$$ \psi_r(x)=\frac{U_r}{\sqrt{2\pi\alpha}}e^{irk_Fx}e^{-i(r\phi(x)-\theta(x))} $$
where $U_r$ is the Klein factor, $\psi_r$ is the fermion field. The limit $\alpha \to 0$ is also understood. Right after this equation, the book says that 
$$e^{-i(r\phi(x)-\theta(x))}$$
varies slowly at the scale of $k_F^{-1}$ and some approximations using this fact are made several pages later. My question is:

1. Why does the above field slowly varying? Is there physical meaning of this approximation?
2. I heard that bosonization is a technique for obtaining exact solution of some 1D systems. But we are using "approximations"! Can we argue that the solution obtained by this method exact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bosonization is exact in the sense that it is not a perturbation method. The approximation we make is that we can linearize the dispersion, and so are limited to states close to the Fermi surface. Within this linear model the solution is exact.

Since we are assuming all the physics takes place near the Fermi level, we can factor out the shift in the zero of momentum and write 
$$\psi_r(x) \propto e^{irkx} e^{i\eta(x)} $$
Where $\eta(x)$ is slowly varying compared to the Fermi wavelength. Any structure on a scale smaller than this would imply that there are excitation far above or far below the Fermi level, at which point bosonization will fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have a question that, why slowly-varying $\eta(x)$ implies the excitation near the Fermi level. I think this concept is not only limited for 1D system and is more general. Could you suggest a reference for that?

Comment: I mean, it is just the uncertainty principle. If (the interesting bit of) our field is localised in momentum space, say near near the Fermi level, then (the interesting bit of) our field must be spread out, i.e. slowly varying, in real space (and its logarithm should vary even slower).

Comment: What does it mean by the "field" being localized? I know the meaning of the "wavefunction" being localized, and the uncertainty principle is valid in that case. But I cannot imagine how this argument can be applied to "field".

Comment: It means the same thing as a wavefunction being localised; the field is zero (or vanishingly small) everywhere except in a small region. I am talking about the uncertainty principle in a loose sense here. Any pair of quantities related by a Fourier transform will show the same relation, at least qualititively. Constraining one quantity to a small region will force the other to spread out.

Comment: I understand your argument that both $f$ and the Fourier transform $\hat f$ cannot be simultaneously localized enough. But how is this related to my original question that why slowly varying $\eta(x)$ implies the excitation near the Fermi level?

Comment: Another question is about the interpretation of $e^{ik_Fx}$ in the field operator $\psi_r(x)$. For "wavefunction" (not "field"!), $e^{ikx}$ is the momentum eigenstate. However, we are dealing with "field" now. Can we also argue that $\psi_r(x)$ is somewhat related to momentum $k_F$ state plus some modulation represented by $\eta(x)$?

Comment: The $e^{i k_F x}$ is because we are localising around $k_F$ rather than $0$. There is a general relation for Fourier transforms that $\mathcal{F}\{f(x-a)\} = e^{i a k} \mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}$, that is translations in real space give a phase factor in frequency space an vise versa.

Comment: The smallest features of my field in real space correspond to the largest scale features in momentum space, so If my field is zero outside some region in momentum space, the largest feature my field has in momentum space is the size of that region, call it $K$, and so no feature of the field in real space can be smaller than around $\frac{2\pi}{K}$, in other words the field *cannot vary on scale smaller than $\frac{2\pi}{K}$*, that is it has to vary more slowly with $x$ than 1 over the size of the region spread over in momentum.

Comment: I understand that part. So you are arguing that if $\eta$ varies slowly, than the Fourier transform of the field $\psi$ is localized at $k_F$ and vice versa. But my question is, how is this fact related to the approximation "consider only near the Fermi level"? Is there physical meaning that the field operator $\psi_r$ has a Fourier transform that is localized near $k_F$? That's the main question.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $\psi_r$ is given by the Fermion annihilation operators $c_{r,k}$, essentially by definition. If $k$ is far above $k_F$ then these operators annihilate the state and if $k$ is far below $k_F$ then they will definitely annihlate the electron present, so this is also not very interesting. Only close to the Fermi level is the action of these operators more complicated. In other words the Fourier transform of $\psi_r(x)$ is localised around the Fermi level and we are free to focus our attention on these states exclusively, allowing us to linearize the dispersion

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explanation was nearly exactly I want. Maybe this will be the last question. I cannot understand this part: " In other words the Fourier transform of ψ_r(x) is localized around the Fermi level."

Comment: If $k$ is far above the Fermi level, then $c_k$ will annihilate the state, so I understand that the Fourier component of $\psi$ for $k>>k_F$ will be nearly zero. But how about $k<<k_F$? In this case $c_k$ does not annihilate the state and we cannot say the Fourier component of $\psi$ for $k<<k_F$ is zero. (If it were true then we can argue that the Fourier component of $\psi$ is localized near $k_F$.)

Comment: It is not 0, but it is also not doing anything interesting. It will give the same contribution for all physically reasonable states. You can imagine writing $\psi(x)$ as the fourier transform of a step function plus another bit. The other bit does everything interesting; the step function is just background. If you really want to work out what happened to the step function bit it will be burried somewhere in the treatment of the ground state (since that is all the ground state has) in setting up the bosonization procedure.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer. Thanks a lot.